# Date calculation in c# for specific set of days

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I have [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388610/date-calculation-in-c-sharp) for date calculation for "Bussines days".
 And finaly I use mechanism described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1044821/1616443).
 But this is the particular case.

What about more general approach?
How add specific number (`n`) of days to current date considering only the days from custom set: `Mn-Tu-We` or `Sa-Su-Me` or any other.

```
Test data 1:
Date: (28-jun-2014).
Days to add: 10
Days type: Mn - Th - Fr
Answer: 21-july-2014

Test data 2:
Date: (28-jun-2014).
Days to add: 5
Days type: Tu - We
Answer: 15-july-2014
```

Comment: any try from yourside so far?

Comment: While doing this *efficiently* would be relatively tricky, if you've only got a few days to add (as in your examples), it should be very simple to just add a day at a time.

Comment: Yes, we can use the mechanism, which I provide in question(link "here"), but it takes a lot of conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From one of the ans specified in link I can make some modification here :-

For test 1:-

```
DayOfWeek[] daysOfWeek= { DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Thursday, DayOfWeek.Friday};
DateTime end = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
            .Select(i => DateTime.Today.AddDays(i))
            .Where(d => daysOfWeek.Contains(d.DayOfWeek))
            .Take(10)
            .Last();
```

**Answer :- 21-07-2014 00:00:00**

For test 2 :-

```
DayOfWeek[] daysOfWeek= { DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DayOfWeek.Wednesday};
DateTime end = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
            .Select(i => DateTime.Today.AddDays(i))
            .Where(d => daysOfWeek.Contains(d.DayOfWeek))
            .Take(5)
            .Last();
```

**Answer :- 15-07-2014 00:00:00**

Comment: Considering that every time you call `DateTime.Today` it's reading from the system clock, you might consider pulling that out into it's own variable.  Then the function will be deterministic - and slightly faster.

Comment: oh yes agree with you @MattJohnson